# How to unset a ">" echo in Linux

Tags: linux, stdout

I've just realized I don't know how to unset an echo I set with `>`.

The exact current situation is I just set `dmesg > /var/log/syslog` and now wanted to unset it, realizing I've never done that before. I know I could restart, but I'd rather learn from someone with more experience.

Sorry if this is answered somewhere else, but I don't know what it is called when you set a location to echo with a `>`, so my queries were bound to fail.

Thanks all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`>` redirections last for the duration of the process, most probalbably `dmesg` has finished so you need do nothing further to stop it.

If however you did `dmesg -w` and it's still running, typing `ctrl`-`c` will stop it.

Comment: I left out details and you still figured out what I did. Thank you--I'll mark your answer as soon as it lets me.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't really "unset" what you've done though. Since what you did is "overwrite /var/log/syslog with the output of dmesg".

So your previous system logs are probably gone. It's sort of harmless though.

Comment: FWIW, if you used >> instead of >, it would be "append" instead of "overwrite".